# Ceva, Desargues and Pascal's theorems for conics

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry

I was told in class today that these three theorems are valid in projective geometry and with conic sections (I'm taking a modern geometry class) but I can't seem to find proofs anywhere online, and I've googled them. Would they be very different from their standard forms? Can you please help me with the proofs?
Thanks

Comment: What does "and with conic sections" mean? The theorems can hold in some geometry, or fail.

Comment: the teacher sort of explained that Desargues theorem, in a way, defines a conic, and that Pascal's can be generalized for conics.

Comment: Any more explanation would help a lot. As it stands, I can't see what this means.

Comment: well, how would ceva's theorem work in projective geometry?

Comment: [like this?](https://math.osu.edu/sites/math.osu.edu/files/ceva-menelaus.pdf)

Comment: I see projective geometry being mentioned but not actually used

Comment: There are references for three projective proofs. You didn't check any of them? OK, well [here's another one](http://books.google.com/books?id=VVvGc8kaajEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=wylie+introductino+to+projective+geometry&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hqJ9VPHxL8aMyAS1joGABw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Ceva's%20theorem&f=false) starting page 309.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm not aware of any connection of these theorems with conic sections other than the possibility of a conic section appearing in the *diagram* describing the configuration. The theorem itself would be in whatever geometry (real projective/Euclidean) that we are talking about.

And even then, the only one I'm aware of at present is for Pascal's theorem. The following scan is taken from Kaplansky's *Linear algebra and geometry: a second course* page 119, an awesome and inexpensive book which I would recommend to anyone:

[image]

Here are the basic things to keep in mind when thinking about these theorems:

1. affine and projective geometry (in the sense of Artin or Kaplanksy) in 3 or more dimensions always satisfy Desargues' theorem.
2. Some planes do not satisfy Desargues theorem or Pascal's theorem
3. Planes which can be built as $D\times D$ for a division ring $D$ are Desarguesian, in fact, this characterizes Desarguesian planes.
4. If a plane $D\times D$ for a division ring $D$ satisfies Pascal's theorem, $D$ is actually a field.
5. A chief tool for converting affine or Euclidean theorems to projective theorems is to replace orthogonality, midpoints and distances with the cross ratio. It's rather involved for me to explain here, but Kaplansky's book does a great job, as I imagine Coxeter's books do too.

Answer (score 0):

The [theorem of Desargues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27_theorem) is true in the real projective plane, but not in every projective plane: there exist [non-Desarguesian planes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Desarguesian_plane). I'm not perfectly sure, but I assume that [Pascal's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem) should be not only a generalization of but also a consequence of [Pappos' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_hexagon_theorem), which in turn means you have a projective plane over some field. For [Ceva's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem) you obviously need lengths, unless you reformulate it in terms of cross ratios. In any case, when you write “valid in projective geometry”, I guess what you really mean is “valid in the *real* projective plane”.

In a certain sense, all of these theorems are not only valid in that real projective plane, but essentially live in projective geometry. If you reformulate them for Euclidean geometry, you'll have to handle a bunch of special cases which are not special at all in projective geometry.

Take [Desargues' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27_theorem), for example. You can formulate that like this:

> If $Aa$, $Bb$ and $Cc$ meet in a single point, then the intersections of $AB$ with $ab$, $AC$ with $ac$ and $BC$ with $bc$ lie on a single line.

But that's the projective formulation. The corresponding Euclidean formulation would be something like this:

> If $Aa$, $Bb$ and $Cc$ either meet in a single point or are parallel to one another, then one of three things can happen. Either the intersection points of $AB$ with $ab$, $AC$ with $ac$ and $BC$ with $bc$ all exist and lie on a single line. Or none of these intersection points exists, since all three pairs of lines are parallel. Or exactly one pair of lines is parallel, in which case the line joining the other two points of intersection is parallel to them as well.

Obviously this looks a lot more complicated and bulky. That's one good reason to interpret the theorem in projective geometry, where parallelism is no special case. The proof in projective geometry is easier as well, since one doesn't have to proove the special cases either.

Comment: Do you have any insight on the title question (*for conics*)?

Comment: @rschwieb: First off, I'm fairly certain that this “for conics” only refers to Pascal's theorem, not the other two. Perhaps there is some other theorem attributed to Pascal and the addition of that phrase is intended to disambiguate. Personally I don't recall anything being called Pascal's theorem except for this theorem for conics.

Comment: It makes sense if the *diagram* is supposed to involve a conic, if that's what was meant. I had the same thoughts you described.